# Get several documents by alternative ID in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My documents have an alternative Id fields. I need to get them using it.

So, I know I'm able to use a `multiget` operation, however, this one needs I provide the `ElsticSearch document id`.

I'm actually trying something like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query":{
     "filtered":{
        "filter":{
           "term":{
              "resources.source.sourceId.batch":"3fcb8905-a307-11e5-88de-382c4ab9e433"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

How could I request a query in order for ElasticSearch to provide every document that has `resources.source.sourceId.batch eq to [id1, or id2, or ...]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `term` you can use [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) and pass an array of values you want to fetch.

```
curl -XGET 'http://ESNode01:9201/living_team/inputs/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "terms":{
          "resources.source.sourceId.batch": ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```